# How to get inverse of integer?

Tags: python, math

I am not sure of inverse is the proper name, but I think it is.

This example will clarify what I need:

I have a max height, 5 for example, and so height can range from 0 to 4. In this case we're talking integers, so the options are: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

What I need, given an input ranging from 0 up to (and including) 4, is to get the inverse number.

Example:
input: 3
output: 1

visual:
0 1 2 **3** 4
4 3 2 **1** 0

I know I can do it like this:

```
position_list = list(range(5))
index_list = position_list[::-1]
index = index_list[3]
```

But this will probably use unnecessary memory, and probably unnecessary cpu usage creating two lists. The lists will be deleted after these lines of code, and will recreated every time the code is ran (within method). I'd rather find a way not needing the lists at all.

What is an efficient way to achieve the same? (while still keeping the code readable for someone new to the code)

Comment: I think the correct term would be "complement", as in a pair of [complementary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/complementary) numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it just `max - in`...?

```
>>> MAX=4
>>> def calc(in_val):
...   out_val = MAX - in_val
...   print('%s -> %s' % ( in_val, out_val ))
...
>>> calc(3)
3 -> 1
>>> calc(1)
1 -> 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to subtract from the `max`:

```
def return_inverse(n, mx):
    return mx - n
```

---

For the proposed example:

```
position_list = list(range(5))
mx = max(position_list)

[return_inverse(i, mx) for i in position_list]
# [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have maximum heigth, let's call it `max_h`.

Your numbers are counted from 0, so they are in `[0; max_h - 1]`

You want to find the complementation number that becomes `max_h` in sum with input number

It is `max_h - 1 - your_number`:

```
max_height = 5

input_number = 2

for input_number in range(5):
    print('IN:', input_number, 'OUT:', max_height - input_number - 1)
```

> ```
> IN: 1 OUT: 3
> IN: 2 OUT: 2
> IN: 3 OUT: 1
> IN: 4 OUT: 0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply compute the reverse index and then directly access the corresponding element.

```
n = 5
inp = 3

position_list = list(range(n))
position_list[n-1-inp]
# 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just derive the index from the list's length and the desired position, to arrive at the "inverse":

```
position_list = list(range(5))
position = 3
inverse = position_list[len(position_list)-1-position]
```

And:

```
for i in position_list:
    print(i, position_list[len(position_list)-1-i])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just have the `output` = `4-input`. If it's just increments of 1 up to some number a simple operation like that should be enough. For example, if the max was 10 and the min was 5, then you could just do `9-input+5`. The 9 can be replaced by the `max-1` and the `5` can be replaced with the `min`.

So `max-1-input+min`